# Align multiple D3 circles in an arc or semi-circle pattern

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

This is one of my first d3 visualizations that's not a straightforward bar/line chart, so apologies if this question seems very basic. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maureenlinke/jMMSJ/

I have about 100 data points, for each I'm generating a circle svg element. However, I'd like the circles to dynamically line up in the shape of an arc or half circle. I'm not sure the best way to go about this. To bind the circles to a path, or an arc? I want this to be dynamic so I don't want to specify each cx and cy coordinate. I played around with the transform/translate option also but that doesn't seem to work either. This could be a simple calculation but I just need to better understand the overall approach.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg");


var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("transform", "translate(220,400) scale(1, -1)")
.attr("cx", function(d,i){return ((i*10)-1);})
.attr("cy", function(d,i){return (i*10);})
.attr("r", 6.15)
.attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is some simply trigonometry to determine the x and y coordinates for the circles:

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i){ return Math.cos(i / (data.length - 1) * cover) * circleRadius; })
.attr("cy", function(d,i){ return Math.sin(i / (data.length - 1) * cover) * circleRadius; })
```

Here, `circleRadius` is the radius of the circle the points should be on and `cover` is the arc segment they should cover (in radians). This will start the circle at the 3 o'clock position, which is probably not what you want in this case -- add an offset to make it a "top" arc.

Apart from that, you just need to translate the container element to accommodate the circles. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jMMSJ/1/).

Comment: Thanks Lars, that's really helpful. If I want to start a new lineo of circles inside the semi circle that I've just drawn, how would I go about that? Since it's over 100 data points the circle has to be very wide to accommodate all of them so I'd like to nest them.

Comment: You just have to change the circle radius for the new "row".

Comment: I understand that piece but if the row is a continuation of the data, rather than a separate row of new data -- how do you denote that? Say if data[i] > 100 start a new circle?

Comment: I would separate those into separate arrays. If you can't/don't want to do that, you can check in the code what `i` is and return the appropriate radius.